# signal strength in real time : how fast is it updated?

Tags: real-time, signal-strength

I am scientist working on a project related to wireless communications.
In my project I need to have access to the phone signal strength, or Binary error rate, or anything that indicates the quality of the received signal.
I know that it is possible to do so on Android using SignalStrength, but I just don't have any idea how fast it is updated.
Can anybody please tell me what is the update time of such variable ?
Many thanks in advance.

G.

Comment: What kind of scientist are you?

Comment: research scientist, doing wave physics (academia)

Comment: Stack Overflow is focused on programming questions, and while this is undoubtedly _software_-related, you may have better luck at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/, where I know there are engineers who care about things like the refresh rate of a Bluetooth signal.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that !